# Facebook OG Tags cache my old server

Tags: facebook, caching, tags, server, facebook-opengraph

I'm facing a big problem with the Facebook debugger. I've read a tons of topics about the Facebook cache etc ... but nothing like mine.

I recently changed my server, so the new one runs perfectly, while the old one is closed.

The problem is Facebook don't see the change and keeps scanning the old server. I know it because the title is a 404 and when I click on "*See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL*" it returns "*Document returned no data*".

The problem is for every single pages but if you want to test one, for example :
http://sayitwithkittens.io/cat/40

What Facebook debugger see : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsayitwithkittens.io%2Fcat%2F40

I would like to upload a screen of the parsing but I don't have the necessary reputation yet..

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: How does your server render the `/cat/40` url?

Comment: It's just a url rewriting. The "true" page is kitten.php?id=40

Comment: If I request http://sayitwithkittens.io/kitten.php?id=40 I get a 200 with an empty response

Comment: Oh, the attribute is id_image, sorry. 
http://sayitwithkittens.io/kitten.php?id_image=40 should work :)

But the debugger still doesn't understand that the server has changed

Comment: Did you update both the IPV4 and IPV6 records for your domain? When I check from my laptop i get an IPV6 address, which returns a 404 for that URL - http://pastebin.com/tDbhHZZL

Comment: Oh god it works ! I forgot to update the ipv6 ! And I didn't see that the field "Server IP" from the debugger is an ipv6. Thank you very much @Igy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by Igy :

> Did you update both the IPV4 and IPV6 records for your domain? When I check from my laptop i get an IPV6 address, which returns a 404 for that URL